# Is 75 years too old to run for president?

Tags: united-states, president, election-requirements

For example, Bernie Sanders would have been 75 years old if he ran as a candidate in the 2016 presidential election. Would that have made him unfit to be president because of his old age? I believe it could have been a problem later on if he had been elected.

Comment: 'Unfit' is going to be mostly opinion based.

Comment: Perhaps we could rephrase to "Is Bernie Sanders significantly older than historical presidents and presidential candidates?"

Comment: @lazarusL - That'd be a interesting question... I'm not sure whether it's what this OP wants to know, though.

Answer (score 4):

Under the Constitution of the United States, a person must be at least [35 years old](http://definitions.uslegal.com/a/age-of-candidacy/) to be President or Vice President.

There is no corresponding maximum age limit. Should his age affect his health, there will be no constitutional obligation for him to resign, although there will be pressure if it creates a hindrance on doing his duties.

Comment: Good answer to a very iffy question.  It's worth mentioning that the President *can* be forced out, either by impeachment or being declared unfit, should the appropriate people decide it's necessary.